# Making and handling an OPTIONS preflight in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, rest

I'm working on front-end code in Marionette that interacts with a RESTful hypermedia service over secure HTTP, and want to determine what options (GET, POST, DELETE - the usual culprits) any given endpoint exposes to the current session. To do so, I've coded up a standard cross-domain jQuery.ajax() call with type: 'OPTIONS' among its parameters. The problem is that jQuery returns no Access-Control-Allow-Methods header for this request.

Is this something that jQuery (or JS) is ill-suited-to, or am I missing something here?

Comment: Have you verified that CORS is set up correctly on the server? This might not be a jquery issue, it might be that the server is refusing the CORS request or not replying properly. You can see this in the network tab in F12 debug tools in chrome, you should be able to see all the headers the server is returning.

Comment: Do you mean that the OPTIONS request comes back correctly, but you simply can't access the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` response header with `getResponseHeader`? If so, the server needs to send `Access-Control-Expose-Headers: Access-Control-Allow-Origin` to allow the client to read that non-simple response header.

Comment: We've verified that the server is exposing the Allow-Methods header via cURL calls, so that doesn't seem to be the source of the issue.

Comment: I've since found that CORS has only six permitted headers. The one I meant to use to inform client-side code of what an endpoint will allow isn't on that list. This limitation is hard-coded into the current webkit, so monkey-patching XMLHttpRequest can't work for that browser.